# Как с помощью jQuery сделать radio из disabled в enabled ?

Tags: jquery

```
<input type="radio" id="step1" enabled checked />
<input type="radio" id="step2" disabled /> // Вот тут делаю disabled
```

Сделал так:

```
$('#register').click(function(){
$('input[name="step2"]').attr('checked', 'checked'); // он работает
$('input[name="step2"]').attr('enabled', 'disabled'); // Но он все же остается disabled
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('input[name="step2"]').prop('disabled', false);
```

Answer (score 0):

У свойств типа enabled (а также checked) есть такая любопытная особенность - вы можете указать в них что угодно - если это свойство есть, то именно оно и будет работать. Чтобы было понятнее, пример:

```
<input type="radio" id="step1" enabled = 'enabled' />
<input type="radio" id="step2" enabled = 'disabled' />

<input type="radio" id="step3" disabled = 'enabled' />
<input type="radio" id="step4" disabled = 'disabled' />
```

Первые два инпута будут активны, несмотря на разницу в содержимом атрибута enabled. А вторые два будут неактивны, тоже несмотря на разницу в содержимом атрибута disabled

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/ffSWJ/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ffSWJ/1/ :)